# how to convert this malformed string to json with php/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have this string -

```
{

          'Carlos':

           {
             Name: 'Spers',
             href: "http://google.com"
           }, 
          'Winter':

           {
             Name: 'Warres',
             href: "http://yahoo.com"
           }, 
          'Doer':

           {
             Name: 'Pinto',
             href: "http://carpet.com"
           } 
}
```

I validated the with JSLinter, it say invalid with multiple errors. And I understand that. The issue is, this is what I get from a third party service. I have to leave with it. Now I'm stuck with it to convert into JSON object to work with it.

When I use `json_decode($thisStirng)` in PHP, it returns null. `$.parseJSON(data)` returns me errors too.

I would like to show the data on the webpage with some styling. So at the end, I want json object at the client to work with. So converting data to JSON with PHP or jQuery, anyway would work.

How should I go about it?

### Update

I got an associative array with `json_decode($thisStirng, true)`. Now I want `echo` it as a string so that on browser, I could access it with array indexes.

Thank you all - got it working as below -

```
 $someObject = json_decode($thisStirng,true);

 $myarry = array();

 foreach ($someObject as $key => $val) {
    $temparray = array();
    $temparray[]= $key;
    $temparray[]= $val;
    $myarry[]= $temparray;
}

 echo json_encode($myarry);
```

Now in jQuery I can access, `data[index][0]` as 'Carlos' and other dynamic keys. `data[index][1]` is an object with 'Name' and 'href' properies.

Comment: Shouldn't you call `json_decode($thisStirng)` instead of `json_encode($thisStirng)`? Please call [json-last-error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to get more information about the reason, why the previous called `json_decode` has failed.

Comment: Oops! yes, I mean to say `json_decode` only. thank you for pointing out that.

Comment: You have not made it clear where you are trying to use this variable, php or javascript. You should also explain wherre you are getting the json, is it in an ajax response or are you getting it in your php file? You should walk us through the flow of your logic more specifically

Comment: to make it as a valid JSON, name and href should be enclosed with quotes

Comment: If you can literally inject this into a script element, you should be able to salvage it, eg `<script>var obj = <?= $thisString ?>, json = JSON.stringify(obj);</script>`

Comment: @cske it needs more than that

Comment: @Phil I see name & href shoud be escaped too ...

Comment: @Phil: There's also [`v8js`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/v8js.executestring.php), which can evaluate JavaScript from inside your PHP process and turn this JS object literal into a proper PHP array... though it might be quite overkill for this scenario.

Comment: `json_decode(strtr(str_replace(['name','href'],['"name"','"href"'],$thisString),'\'','"')) `

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
 $jsonData='{
      "Carlos":
       {
         "Name": "Spers",
         "href": "http://google.com"
       }, 
      "Winter":

       {
         "Name": "Warres",
         "href": "http://yahoo.com"
       }, 
      "Doer":
       {
         "Name": "Pinto",
         "href": "http://carpet.com"
       } 
}';

$arr1=array();
$arr2=array();
$arr3=array();
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);
foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) { 

    $arr1=array();
    $arr1[]=$key;

    foreach ($value as $k => $v) { 
        $arr2=array();

        $arr2[$k]=$v;
        $arr3[]=$arr2;
    }
}
echo $arr3[0]['Name'];
```

Comment: I'm good with decoding. I got an associative array.  When I do that and try to access element like `echo $someObject[0]["Name"];`, it says - `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 '

Comment: try the edited code. I have stored the values in different offsets of array 3

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
<?php
$jsonData='{
      "Carlos":
       {
         "Name": "Spers",
         "href": "http://google.com"
       }, 
      "Winter":

       {
         "Name": "Warres",
         "href": "http://yahoo.com"
       }, 
      "Doer":
       {
         "Name": "Pinto",
         "href": "http://carpet.com"
       } 
}';
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);


foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key:".$key. ", Name:". $value['Name'].'<br>';

}

?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Key:Carlos, Name:Spers
Key:Winter, Name:Warres
Key:Doer, Name:Pinto
```